# Symbol to represent "On the unit sphere" to laymen

Tags: notation

I am preparing a deck of slides related to quantum computing for network-administrator and business type people which involves the following diagram:

[image: Quantum superposition on the unit circle diagram]

In the text I had $|\Psi> \in \{0,1\}$. I imagine this is fine for a non-mathematical audience, but it makes me uneasy since $\{0,1\}$ is the discrete set of 2 elements, so it's, like, wrong.

**What's a better notation to use?**

I thought of $|\Psi> \in [0,1]^3$, which is closer, but still not quite right since $|\Psi>$ is restricted to the unit sphere.

**Remember**, given my audience, simplicity is better than correctness.

Comment: What point(s) do you need to make that require this information as background?

Comment: Introduce the term $S^2$ and use that?

Comment: I would note first that your drawing is a sphere, not a circle. Plus, since $\Psi$ is a vector in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, given your audience I would simply skip this part.

Comment: @John not much, it's mainly to build intuition on qubits before we talk about Shor's algorithm and factoring (again, in an informal way)

Comment: I use the symbol $\hat\Psi$ to represent a vector with norm $1$.

Answer (score 1):

"Picture an exercise ball with a radius of one foot.  Using extra-strength quantum super-glue we've fastened the tail of a 1-foot-long arrow to the center of the exercise ball, so it's free to pivot in any direction, and the point of the arrow touches the surface of the exercise ball."

"So $\left|1\right>$ happens when the orientation is straight up, and $\left|0\right>$ happens when the orientation is straight down."